# Getting array indicies

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing an algorithm that loops through an array and returns an array containing the indices of numbers that are powers of 2. Thereafter I run a prewritten test on it, but apparently the code doesn't give the intended results. Can anyone please help me identify the flaw in my logic?

```js
function secondPower(arr) {
  let powers = [];
  let x;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //if odd, move on to next iteration
    if (arr[i] % 2 !== 0) continue;

    x = arr[i];

    //keep dividing x for as long as x is even
    do {
      x = x / 2;
    } while (x % 2 === 0);

    //if x equals one, it must have been a power of 2.
    ///Put it in collection array
    if (x === 1) powers.push(i);
  }
  return powers;
}
console.log(secondPower([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

Comment: What is the test that is failing?

Comment: I am getting [1,3,7] for the input that you provided and which seems to be the correct answer

Comment: Those indices are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your indices are correct - you do not get the numbers but their positions

This can be shortened

Testing the number is a power of 2 using Math

`(Math.log(num)/Math.log(2)) % 1 === 0`

1 is a power of 2 as well (2**0)

Here I [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) by pushing the index and number if number is a power of 2. I return the accumulator using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

The function itself and the reduce are using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

If you ONLY want the indices, change `acc.push({[i]:num})` to `acc.push(i)`

```js
const powerOfTwo = arr => arr
  .reduce((acc,num,i) => (((Math.log(num)/Math.log(2)) % 1 === 0) && acc.push({[i]:num}), acc),[]);   
console.log(powerOfTwo([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,64,1024]))
```

Even shorter using [bitwise AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND)

The `&` operator does a bitwise AND operation on two numbers.
`num & -num` sets all bits of num to 0 except for the least significant 1 bit.

If num is a power of 2, then `num` and `-num` will have only this least significant bit in common, and expression returns num if yes, 0 if no

```js
const powerOfTwoIdx = arr => arr
  .reduce((acc, num,i) => ((num === (num & -num) && acc.push(i)),acc),[]) 
console.log(powerOfTwoIdx([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 64, 1024]))

const powerOfTwoFilter = arr => arr
  .filter(num => num === (num & -num)) 
console.log(powerOfTwoFilter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 64, 1024]))
```

Comment: I appreciate it. I'm afraid this is beyond my comprehension. Would you mind giving a brief overview of what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let pow = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{
  if(arr[i] && (!(arr[i]&(arr[i]-1))))
  {
    pow.push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(pow);
```

use bit shift

Comment: Maybe some more comments?

Comment: https://skorks.com/2010/10/write-a-function-to-determine-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2/

Comment: enough ? or add something

Comment: `!(arr[i]&(arr[i]-1)` is a little hairy ;) but yeah.

Comment: thank you you made my day "little hairy"